# How do I validate password on the base of a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I want the password should be mandatory for web registration only and not for mobile app registration.
My validation code is below:

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    validate :password_for_web
    validate :password_confirmation_for_web

  def password_for_web
    if  !app_user && password.blank? 
    errors.add(:password, "can't be blank.")
  end
end

 def password_confirmation_for_web
   if  !app_user && password != self.password_confirmation=
       errors.add(:password_confirmation, "doesn't match.")
   end
 end

 end
```

Validation is working properly but when in case of mobile app registration it is still requiring password. Help regarding the issue would be appreciable.

Comment: What is the difference in registration process web/app ?

Comment: For mobile api registration we only require phone number not password but for web registration password is mandatory. I need sort of custom validation function which can differentiate between web registration and api registration. There is a flag which I have set is app_user:boolean. If true means that registration is from api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `if:` and `unless:` options to toggle validations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, unless: :app_user?
  # or 
  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, if: :web_user?

  # TODO implement app_user?
end
```

You can pass a symbol (a method name) or a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using simple rails app with responsive design.**

You need to first check device is mobile or other device. This you can do in many ways.

Custom Way :

In application_helper.rb:

```
def mobile_device
  agent = request.user_agent
  return "tablet" if agent =~ /(tablet|ipad)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i
  return "mobile" if agent =~ /Mobile/
  return "desktop"
end
```

Then you can use it in your views:

```
<% if mobile_device == "mobile" %>
    //add extra parameter to check in model
    <% form_tag :mobile_device, true %>
<% end %>
```

In your model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :password_for_web, if: :mobile_device?
  validate :password_confirmation_for_web, if: :mobile_device?

  def password_for_web
    if  !app_user && password.blank? 
        errors.add(:password, "can't be blank.")
    end
  end

  def password_confirmation_for_web
    if  !app_user && password != self.password_confirmation=
    errors.add(:password_confirmation, "doesn't match.")
    end
  end

  def mobile_device?
    mobile_device.present?
  end
end
```

You can also use gems to check mobile device like:

https://github.com/fnando/browser

https://github.com/shenoudab/active_device

**If you have separate mobile app.**

Add extra parameter in your registration form for mobile application like I used in my view with name `mobile_device`. Use updated model code and you are done.

Comment: Thanks @Dipak Gupta, using the term app_user I meant REST Api request not request from mobile device but request from mobile app.

Comment: You can use extra parameter in api if request from mobile app. On basis of that you can run conditional callback

Comment: Yes I have used app_user, please look at my custom validation method. It is not receiving any bool value which is being sent from mobile app as app_user=true, actually the problem is this